# VS built .dll accessed in gcc built program: wrong call gets executed

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, mingw-w64

I am having issues getting the correct code to execute when I access VS/CL built DLL used in a project compiled with GCC.

so I have an engine.dll,
with a public facing header `Engine.hpp`

```
    class EngineDLL
    {
            public:
            virtual ~EngineDLL() {}
            virtual long EngineServerClientHandshake(const char* username, const char* password) = 0;
            virtual long EngineGetHealthInfo() = 0;
            virtual long EngineGetLastError(char* fault, size_t fault_size) = 0;
            virtual long EngineShutDown() = 0;
    };

typedef EngineDLL* (__cdecl *CreateModule)();
```

In the non public implementation header `EngineImp.hpp`:

```
    class EngineImp : public EngineDLL
    {
        public:
            EngineImp(); // Default constructor
            ~EngineImp();
            
            long EngineServerClientHandshake(const char* username, const char* password);
            long EngineGetHealthInfo();
            long EngineGetLastError(char* fault, size_t fault_size);
            long EngineShutDown();
                
        private:
            int add_client_username_token();            
    };


//To provide access to this Engine.dll I use this method

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) EngineDLL* __cdecl CreateModule()
    {
        EngineDLL* module = new EngineImp();
        return module;
    }
```

In a VS project the following works:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"Engine.dll");


    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        CreateModule createModule = reinterpret_cast<CreateModule>(GetProcAddress(hModule, "CreateModule"));        
        EngineDLL* EngineInstance = createModule();
    }
```

And the `EngineInstance` successfully makes all the calls with no issue.

However, when I attempt to make the same calls on a gcc built program with the same code

```
EngineInstance->EngineServerClientHandshake(l_username,l_password);
```

the call `EngineGetHealthInfo()` gets executed

Similarly, if I make the

`EngineInstance->EngineGetHealthInfo()`

call, then `EngineGetLastError` call gets executed.

All in all, it **looks like one call ahead than what is in the `EngineDLL` header file gets executed, instead of the actual call.** I can build this program and use it in my debugger for the DLL project, and see the wrong call getting executed.

It looks like something to do with the calling conventions in regards to how I am exporting the `EngineDLL*` instance, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

The.dll uses x64 build configuration on Visual Studio, and I use x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0 for gcc

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks ahead.

Comment: You cannot just mix and match objects compiled with different compilers. Compile *everything* with the *same* compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ohh. I was under the impression that this would be OK as long as no complex types were involved and the calling conventions were modified correctly. 

So... in order to use this .dll in a gcc built project, I would have to have a different version compiled with gcc?

Comment: I would say that using classes with virtual functions fails the requirements for "no complex types".

Comment: @C.O. if the 2 modules have been built with different tool-chains then the only usable interface types are the plain `C` types.  Even then you need to be very aware of where memory is allocated and de-allocated, as allocating in one module and trying to free it in the other module won't work.

Comment: @RichardCritten So.. Instead of attempting to extract an instance from a module that was built with a different compiler, I should probably only extract individual functions that that are all defined with extern C... and I'll have a better chance ?

Comment: Yes and these functions should only use `C` types as their parameters.  You need to take care that any heap memory is destroyed in the same module that allocated it.